# Is there a way to print different list elements depending on input?

Tags: python, list

I have this python code

```
color = input("Color? ")
color_list = ["orange", "red", "green", "blue", "pink"]

if color in color_list:
    if color == "orange":
        print("This is orange")
    elif color == "red":
        print("This is red")
else:
  print("Color invalid")
```

Is there a way to print different elements of the list on the same `print()` so I don't have to write an `elif:` for every color on the list

Sorry if you couldn't understand me, I'm still learning English.

Comment: Why don't you just print `color`?

Comment: You already checked if it was in the list, why then check which specific thing in the list it is?

Comment: No need to use if statements here use a simple `f string`: `print(f'This color is {color}')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd only print the name of the color if it's found in the list, then you can just

```
color = input("Color? ")
color_list = ["orange", "red", "green", "blue", "pink"]

if color in color_list:
    print(f"This is {color}")
else:
    print("Color invalid")
```

If you'd like to do something else, say, translate colors from English to Finnish, you could use a dictionary:

```
color_map = {
    "orange": "oranssi",
    "red": "punainen",
    "green": "vihreä",
    "blue": "sininen",
    "pink": "vaaleanpunainen",
}

color = input("Color? ")

if color in color_map:
    print(f"{color} in Finnish is {color_map[color]}")
else:
    print("Sorry, I don't know what that is in Finnish")
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe your code can be shortened like this

```
color = input("Color? ")
color_list = ["orange", "red", "green", "blue", "pink"]

# check if the color is in the list
if color in color_list:
    # if there is, it means color is one of the colors from the list
    # so you just have to output it
    print("This is " + color)
else:
  print("Color invalid")
```

Comment: The question is already answered and your answer is the same as the correct answer for the question